# can a slave plugin ssh to Jenkins on the same server as the Jenkins itself

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-agent

I'm trying to plugin the slave that is installed in the same server as jenkins, in order to cut, number of separate VM's machine running about. I'm new to jenkins installation, just learning on the go.

1. Can i use the same server as slave plugin ssh
2. Jenkins is failed with the below given message, when i tried to use the slave ssh plugin, which is in the same server, should add the key of its own? if so, how do i generate one.

> ```
> [11/16/18 15:59:16] [SSH] WARNING: No entry currently 
>  exists in the Known Hosts file for this host. Connections will be denied 
>  until  this new host and its associated key is added to the Known Hosts file.
> ```

would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Slave nodes are used in Jenkins as a best practice to run builds because running it on master is not secure as anyone can access JENKINS_HOME directory and make modifications via jobs. See [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=97092114#content/view/97092114) link. I’d recommend you run a separate single slave node with multiple executors configured so you are able to run multiple builds in parallel and is easier to maintain. Or run dynamic slaves (Docker containers) on the slave node.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your comments. Could you please let me know, how to use the dynamic slaves? if you could share me a link it would be very helpful.

Comment: @vcnr_1234 I used https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/ to setup dynamic slaves. Please accept the answer if it helped!

Comment: Hi, I marked it as an answer, but unfortunately, it wont be recorded. Since i haven't earned 15 reputations yet.